# System of equations after reducing vectors

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

**Part a)**: Find the real number k such that the equation has no solutions in a and b.

This was originally a vector problem, but I reduced this down to a system of equations:

$b – 2 = 2a$

$-2b -2 = ka$. Any hints for the next step?

**Part b)**: Find the real number k such that the equation has **infinitely many** solutions in a and b.

This was also a vector problem, but different vectors were used. I reduced this down to a system of equations:

$-4b-3 = 8a-4$

$b = -2a+k$.   Any hints for the next step for this one as well?

Thank you!

Comment: You know any linear algebra? Specifically row reduction / Gaussian elimination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Each linear equation defines a line on the plane, and each solution to a system of two linear equations is a common point to those lines. How can it be that there is not any solution (intersection points) at all or an infinite number of them? Try to stablish this in terms of the slope of each line.

Comment: If there's not any intersection points, the two lines would have to be parallel. This means that the slopes would be equal/the same. If there are an infinite number of solutions, the two lines would have to be...the same line?

Comment: That's right. And two lines are the same if they have the same slope and a common point. Notice that in the first case, the lines must be parallel and they cannot have ANY point in common, but that's not an issue, indeed.

Comment: For part a), would k = 4? and for part b), would k = 1/4? Let me know if you would like me to "show my work" for both parts.

Comment: The first one should be $-4$, the second one is correct.

Comment: When entering in -4 for the first question, it came up as incorrect. I will double check my problem statement to make sure I did not accidentally include any typos.

Comment: There was indeed a typo, but after using the hint, I figured out the problem. Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to choose the accepted answer whenever you want to.